# I want to print array in reverse order, I tried to code for the same as shown in the attached picture but I am not understanding why is 0 being shown?

Tags: c++, arrays

this is the code which I tried

```
int main(){

int n;

cout<<"Type the number of elements\n";
cin>>n;

cout<<"Type the integars";
int arr[n];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

    cin>>arr[i];

}
cout<<"This is the reversed array ";

for(int i=n;i>=0;i--){

    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}

return 0;
}
```

this is the output pls explain why is 0 coming where did I go wrong?

[image]

Comment: You read n integers in the first for-loop but you try to print out n+1 integers in the second.  Start at int i = n-1 in your second for-loop and you're good.

Comment: The final loop n = 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0  - 6 iterations for an array of length 5.  `arr[5]` is out-of-bounds.  Start with `int i = n - 1`

Comment: Even if you fix the off by one error, [VLAs are not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) so your code isn't actually valid. Please take a look at `std::vector`.

Comment: Change your starting point to `int i = n - 1` while printing reversed array

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your reversed array starts at `n`, and `arr[n]` is invalid, because the array starts at 0.

```cpp
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array is of size 5, but you're accessing 6 elements instead 5. That is, you are accessing elements 5...0 (6 in total) when the array only has 4...0 (5 in total) elements.

Start the 2nd for loop with n-1 and that should solve your issue. That is, (for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)) instead of (for(int i=n;i>=0;i--))

Answer (score 0):

Solution: To print use i = n - 1

```
int main(){

int n;

cout<<"Type the number of elements\n";
cin>>n;

cout<<"Type the integars";
int arr[n];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

    cin>>arr[i];

}
cout<<"This is the reversed array ";

for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){

    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays begin counting at zero through to n (n being the target size value), so you need to ignore the zero value and start printing after zero has been iterated through.

Something like:

```
counter = target -1
```

Answer (score 0):

When printing the reverse of array make sure you remember the position of elements is always one less.
So you have to start with n-1. '0' is getting printed because it is the garbage value at that position it could have been any number or value.

```
int main(){

int n;

cout<<"Type the number of elements\n";
cin>>n;

cout<<"Type the integars";
int arr[n];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

    cin>>arr[i];

}
cout<<"This is the reversed array ";


// When printing the reverse of array make sure you remember the position of elements is always one less.
// So you have to start with n-1. '0' is getting printed because it is the garbage value at that position it could have been any number or value.

for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){  

    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
}

return 0;
}
```